# Why can't I reach my VM from the Win7 host machine?

Tags: networking, windows-7, ip, virtualbox, docker

I have a Linux/Boot2Docker virtual machine running through VirtualBox on Windows 7 Pro. I can't ping or otherwise reach the VM from Windows. (However, pinging my Windows IP from the VM works fine.) Running tracert seems to show that it's looking for the VM on the LAN instead of the VirtualBox adapter, but the routing table looks like it should route the packets correctly.

UPDATE: In the VirtualBox Manager, I linked the VM's network adapter to the Windows Adapter #2 instead of #3, and now I can ping the VM from Windows. Tracert still looks on the LAN but maybe that's a red herring. The VM still isn't doing its real job, but that may be another problem. I'll answer the question if I can confirm that.

Output from tracert:

```
>tracert 192.168.59.103

Tracing route to 192.168.59.103 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.25.80.254
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

IP configuration on Windows:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Private Network :

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::39e9:8769:9302:b800%21
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.184.0
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Corporate Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : pc.mycompany.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::483c:a909:5355:6820%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.25.80.89
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.25.80.205

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::78e7:30fe:75a0:1b27%23
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.59.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10db:8090:da3b:46e3%37
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.70.227
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.pc.mycompany.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : pc.mycompany.com

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8AB45835-1093-4C43-A8A5-6D016FB1B8DE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C3E3838E-D107-4A3D-9CE4-1943D581BEB0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FEADDB5F-620C-4083-9AC3-3E34D663191A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Windows routing table ("route print"):

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 21...00 1b 21 2c e2 a3 ......Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
 10...f0 4d a2 dd 00 4a ......Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
 23...08 00 27 00 18 d1 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
 37...08 00 27 00 e8 47 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 40...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.25.80.205      10.25.80.89     10
       10.25.80.0    255.255.254.0         On-link       10.25.80.89    266
      10.25.80.89  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.80.89    266
     10.25.81.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.80.89    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.184.0    266
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.70.227    276
   169.254.70.227  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.70.227    276
    169.254.184.0  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.184.0    266
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.184.0    266
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.70.227    276
     192.168.59.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.59.3    276
     192.168.59.3  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.59.3    276
   192.168.59.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.59.3    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.59.3    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.25.80.89    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.184.0    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.70.227    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.59.3    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.80.89    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.184.0    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.70.227    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 23    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 37    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 37    276 fe80::10db:8090:da3b:46e3/128
                                    On-link
 21    266 fe80::39e9:8769:9302:b800/128
                                    On-link
 10    266 fe80::483c:a909:5355:6820/128
                                    On-link
 23    276 fe80::78e7:30fe:75a0:1b27/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 23    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 37    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings on the VM

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a [Persistent route](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978475.aspx) so all  network traffic from your machine to VM (192.168.59.130) routes through the concerned NIC(Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2)

> route add -p 192.168.59.103 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.59.3 if 23

Comment: That didn't help, except that now when I ping the VM, the "destination host unreachable" messages come from 192.168.59.3 (the virtual adapter for VirtualBox) instead of from a host on the 10.X.X.X LAN. Tracert still looks on the LAN.

Comment: try adding interface preference as well